# Laravel 5: Multiple submit buttons to save data while navigating the page

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Page one.php has a form with a "Next" button that submits the data to the controller and then redirects to page two.php

On page two.php at the bottom of the form there is a "Previous" button that I want to still save the data but go back to page one.php and also another "Next" button that saves the data and then redirects to three.php and so on.

In Laravel is there a way to do this without duplicating controllers and making it more complicated?

In addition to the buttons there is a navigation menu that would have the same pages so if the user modifies any data they could also click the nav button and then data would be submitted and then go to that next page that they clicked. Is this possible or do I have to have ajax contently listening for form input changes and then posting them to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of sessions. Store the data in session and on every page check if session var exists. After user submits form, empty the session

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#basic-usage